# Embedd color managment LUT into blend file

Tags: color-management, filmic-blender, packed-data

I have started to use filmic-blender, which solves alot of lightning problems (I think it should be embedded into blender as soon as possible). However, now the blend files are not stand-alone, so I cannot just take the blend file, and render it on another machine, without copying the color managment LUTs.

Is it somehow possible to embed that information into the blend file?

Comment: If an equivalent version of blender with the filmic feature is installed on the render machine, it should have the luts. I don't see it as any different than making sure the right version of blender is on the render machine. Is this not the case?

Comment: @ToddMcIntosh The stock blender does not come with that profile. You need to get it separately from GitHub. I want the render to work without the requirement of installing any addons beforehand.

Comment: The current master on the buildbot site has it built in I believe without installing anything extra. It's not in the official release yet though.

Comment: https://builder.blender.org/download/

Comment: I see that blender 2.79 ships with these new profiles by default. As a side note, I claim that it does not matter if you do full path tracing or a simple raster-scanline rendering with the Phong model. The thing that kills your effort is clamped RGB values. Especially for glossy materials in colors other than red yellow green cyan blue magenta, and gray. Reason: these colors have the same intensities across all non-zero channels, making them immune to hue-shifting.